# How does photoelectron yield quantum efficiency change for metals in presence of electric field?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Figure 1 of this paper gives quantum efficiency for stainless steel. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08074.pdf

However, I am interested in photoelectron yield quantum efficiency for stainless steel at 4kV/cm.

Answer (score 1):

For the reasons discussed in ["Does photoelectric work function change with voltage?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/485793/145491), a 4 kV/cm (= 0.04 mV/Å) electric field should have a negligible effect on the metal's work function (energy needed for electron to leave the metal), so the photoelectron yield will likely also not be significantly affected. Atomic [ionization energies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy) are of order 10 eV, and [atomic radii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radii_of_the_elements_(data_page)) are of order 1 Å, so electric fields of order 10 V/Å are needed to remove an electron from an atom.
The work function needed to remove an electron from a metal is typically less than the ionization energy, but is the same order-of-magnitude.

How much an electric field $F$ reduces the work function $W$ was [modelled by Shottky](https://books.google.ca/books?id=y0FF19lud5YC&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q&f=false) as
$$\Delta W = \sqrt{\frac{e^3}{4\pi\epsilon_0} F} = \sqrt{\alpha_{QED} \hbar c F}$$
If my arithmetic is correct, this gives $\Delta W =$ 24 mV for a 4 kV/cm electric field, much smaller than the 4-5 eV work function of most metals (according to the source cited in the question). About a GV/m electric field would be needed to reduce the work function by about 1 eV.

Note, however, that local surface topography or contaminants can dramatically reduce the [local work function needed to remove an electron](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133753/145491) compared to that of an ideal atomically-smooth flat  clean surface. For real materials, electric fields of order a few MV/m are typically enough to start break [corona discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge). Since 4 kV/m = 0.4 MV/m is getting close to this range, some parts of your metal surface - especially any edges, points, or rough bits - may be close to breakdown with much larger local electric fields and hence much bigger reductions in the work function and possible increases in photoelectron yield.

Finally, a 4 kV/cm electric field could increase the effective photoelectron yield by simply increasing the number of electrons reaching your detector. Without an electric field, the low energy electrons can wander in different directions and also be bent by even small magnetic fields. (A photoelectron with only a few eV of kinetic energy can have a $\sim 0.1$ m radius of curvature in the half-Gauss [Earth's magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field).)